# how can I display a log updating in real time in rails 3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I’m a new user of rails3 and ruby and wanted to ask a question on a problem I have

In my app I have a method that takes a list of hosts from the database and will connect to each one over ssh and run a job
The results of the job get appended to a string (think of it as a log), this is all called via a post where the command to run is specified

At the end of the process the log is displayed on a page

So far it all works however the time taken to run all the connections is fairly long (over a minute) so I’m looking to display the results page and show the log file updating in a div until the process is finished (almost in real time)

I’ve done a bit of research and I’m sure I can do this idea using JQuery or something similar, but I don’t know how to do this kind of stuff in a rails environment and all of the tutorials I’ve found don’t really help

This is my code at the moment

**update_controller.rb**

```
def update
  list = Device.all
  c = params[:comm.]
  # create log file
  @create_template = "Log"

  list.each do |device|
    #call method to connect via ssh and run specific command
    @create_template += ssh_connect(device.address, c)
  end

  # show process complete    
  @create_template += "Process Complete" 
end
```

and here is my **update view**

```
<p><b>SSH Connection log</b></p>
<div class="scroll" style="width:30%">
<%=  @create_template.html_safe %>
</div>
```

So if anyone could point me in the direction of any tutorials or give me an idea of things to research I would appreciate it, or you have a way to do it that would be great

Cheers

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Rails 3.1, you should experiment with `HTTP Streaming`.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming

And, of course, you would have to change the code in your controller to stream the log data back to client after connecting to each device.

Also, [deployinator](https://github.com/etsy/deployinator) comes with a `log_and_stream` module which sounds like exactly what you want. Have a look at that.

Comment: Hi, I'm using rails 3.0.7 atm but I can look at upgrading, thanks for the idea of using log and stream I'll do some investigation around that

Comment: As I'm using 3.0.7 I investigated using response_body to stream content back to the browser and have it almost working. the only downside is the streaming only displays a blank page with the output on it, it's lost the page template. I'll continue down this way though as it looks promising and will report back. does anyone know of any gems that might help the only one I found was template_streamer but that doesn't support Rails 3.0